# Tuntap interface odd behavior

Tags: networking, network-interface, ethernet, bsd, macos

I have a program that uses tapcfg to set up a tuntap interface and the interface seems to get setup correctly on the endpoint address I specify which is `169.253.2.100`. I also set up the src address to be `192.168.1.50`.

With ifconfig, I see:

```
tap0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether aa:b6:24:69:77:21 
    inet 169.253.2.100 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 169.253.2.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
    open (pid 3738)
```

However when I check its route entry with I get:

```
route get 169.253.2.100
   route to: 169.253.2.100
destination: 169.253.2.100
  interface: lo0
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,LLINFO,WASCLONED,LOCAL,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0     16384         0
```

Thats not right, the interface should be tap0.

However, checking the route for `169.253.2.50` I see:

```
route get 169.253.2.50
   route to: pptform.state.gov
destination: pptform.state.gov
  interface: tap0
      flags: <UP,HOST,REJECT,DONE,LLINFO,WASCLONED,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500       -18
```

ignoring the resolved DNS of `pptform.state.gov`, we can see that the interface of tap0 is correct.

When I `ping 169.253.2.100`, I get activity on loopback as expected from the output of `route get 169.253.2.100`.
When I ping `169.253.2.50`, I get a request timeout.

Any idea what might be the problem?

I can do

```
sudo route change -host 169.253.2.100 -ifscope tap0
Password:
change host 169.253.2.100
```

but the change doesn't seem to stick.

My program successfully injects `whohas 169.253.2.100` packets into tap0 which show up as having src `169.253.2.50`, but the kernel never responds.

I'm on macOS Catalina which from my experience has a networking behaviors most similar to FreeBSD.